# Nowhere compact subsets of the plane

Tags: gn.general-topology, plane-geometry, compactifications

Suppose $X\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is nowhere compact ($X$ has no compact neighborhood) and non-empty.

Can $X$ be *densely* embedded into the plane?

In other words, is there a dense set $X'\subseteq \mathbb R ^2$ such that $X'\simeq X$?

I believe the answer is yes if $X$ is zero-dimensional.  Is it still true for totally disconnected $X$?

Also I am  primarily interested in Polish spaces.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb Z\times\{0\}$ a counterexample? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean with "nowhere compact".

Comment: Not if $X$ is the $x$-axis together with all rational coordinate points below it...?

Comment: @Wojowu nowhere compact would have to look more like the rationals; discrete spaces are locally compact

Comment: @D.S.Lipham How does it fail your definition of nowhere compact though? $\mathbb Z\times\{0\}$ doesn't have a compact neighbourhood. Perhaps you meant no point of $X$ has a compact neighbourhood in $X$?

Comment: @Wojowu yes I mean neighborhood relative to the subset, not relative to the entire plane

Comment: To make it clear, your definition of "nowhere compact" is something like "For all $x \in X$, there is no open neighborhood $U \ni x$ such that its closure $\bar{U} \subseteq X$ is compact", right?

Comment: Is Erdos space homeomorphic to a dense subset of the plane?

Comment: @RamirodelaVega What is your intuition about this?

Answer (score 5):

According to the definition [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf) a topological space is *nowhere compact* if every compact subset has empty interior. Assuming that's that you mean by "nowhere compact", the following set $X$ seems to be a counterexample for your first question, without "totally disconnected":

$$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R:x^2+y^2\le1\}\setminus\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q:x^2+y^2\lt1\}$$

Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R:x^2+y^2=1\}\subset X$. If $X$ is embedded in the plane, then the image of $S$ is a simple closed curve. Since $X\setminus S$ is connected, its image is either entirely inside or entirely outside that simple closed curve. In either case, the image of $S$ is not dense in the plane.

Comment: BTW this is also a Polish space.

Comment: thank you.  now what about for totally disconnected polish spaces?

Comment: Totally disconnected Polish spaces can have arbitrary high (even infinite) dimension, see Theorem 3.9.3 in the book of van Mill https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-infinite-dimensional-topology-of-function-spaces/van-mill/978-0-08-092977-4

Comment: @TarasBanakh yes but my question is: Can a totally disconnected Polish subspace of the plane be densely embedded into the plane.